# Trouble with finding an app on play store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, search

I'm using Android 6.0 (non-rooted) phone and looking for an application called `call tools optinno`.

*Though* it can be easily found by searching on net : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calltoolsoptinno , *However*, I can't find on play store by searching `call tools optinno` or by `call blocker` etc.

[image]

I've also tried by entering id : `com.calltoolsoptinno` on the play store but didn't get.

Note: I've scrolled down multiple times but can't find the app I'm looking for.

What's wrong with searching mechanism?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid this question is rather "Android independent": we cannot do anything about the search algorithms built into Google's websites. And I bet the whole thing doesn't even run on Android :)

Comment: Why don't you search for "Call blocker and more tools" for a more direct approach?

Comment: @Izzy Is there a SE community/site for/on which this question is suitable?

Comment: @Pandya no idea. Ask Google? #D Not that it didn't annoy me every now and then (you search for the exact name, still get n pages of irrelevant stuff first if the app appears at all). Not always, though...

Comment: It's possibly being filtered out because it's not compatible with whatever device you're searching on.

Comment: @eldarerathis I'm using Android 6.0. Does it show for you?

Comment: There's more to it than just Android version. Developers can also restrict their apps based on geographic location or hardware features. I'm not sure if either of these would be necessary for this particular app, but it's certainly possible. You'd probably have to contact the developer to find out, or you could try visiting the Play Store in a browser that's signed into the same account that's on your phone; then it should tell you if it's incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons - I think -  an app can't be found in Google Play Store: The app is not designed for your phone model and/ or android version and/or it is  a geographic specific app. Use a VPN if it is geographically unavailable for your region/country.

Comment: I've tried VPN but still have the same issue.

Comment: Try this, connect to a VPN, set a country, eg. USA, Go to Settings > Applications > Google Play and clear data & cache then open Google Play, find your app, download. Have fun.